# What's a good way of making headers/footers for Bootstrap list-group-items?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to be able to add my own custom headers, footers, etc to list-group-items.  I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but my css skills are sub-par.  Can anyone show me a good way to fix my attempt?
https://jsfiddle.net/r6xt1rnz/36/

I'd like to be able to insert content into the following sections and have them each take up 33% of a list-group-item.

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="list-header row">
      This is the header
    </div>
    <div class="list-content row">
      This is the content
    </div>
    <div class="list-footer row">
      This is the footer
    </div>
  </li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you telling 33% of vertical height?

Comment: Okay, just got it... I'll see how to make it work.

Comment: So tell me, what exactly are you expecting then? Coz you have used the class `row`, which totally screws up the layout.

Comment: Try using `position: fixed`. Do you want them inside the list item, for sure?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  I'm expecting something like the code snippet you posted but for each list-group-item

Comment: @DavidJ. you are using position:absolute , are you pretty sure with this css? as i think issue is coming from them. use them in proper way..

Comment: @DavidJ. Remove the `row` and bring the three `div`s outside the list item. It would work.

Comment: @Leothelion  Actually your suggestion seems to work and do what I originally wanted.  I simply removed the position: absolute   
https://jsfiddle.net/r6xt1rnz/42/

Comment: @PraveenKumar  But my intention with the divs is to be able to insert content like buttons, etc.  I did remove the row, but what's wrong with the fiddle immediately above?

Comment: @DavidJ. well happy that it works..just a suggestion..whenever using position use them in proper way like with absolute and relative. just little bit practise and then you are good enough to go :)

Comment: The whole structure is wrong. `:(` I am just thinking of giving you a better code. Behold.

Comment: The `position: absolute` elements take the nearest parent, which has `position: relative`. The list items have it.

Comment: @DavidJ. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/8La3352u/

Comment: @PraveenKumar  Maybe I'm not explaining myself clearly enough.  The fiddle I posted above has something similar to what I want to end up with:
https://jsfiddle.net/r6xt1rnz/42/
I'm sure you have a point to make that I'm missing because of my lack of css knowledge, but since your answer isn't applied to a list-group-items, I don't see what makes it superior to mine.  The last fiddle you posted is not what I have in mind -- I don't want static items, just simple items that could become reddit-style list-group-items

Comment: @DavidJ. I can tell I can do whatever possible in CSS. Can you show me a clear, pictorial representation of what you wanna achieve, it would be helpful for me to give you a solution?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  I want to have list-group-items that I can place content in like buttons, text, etc into different slots called header, content, footer.  I think this should give you an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/r6xt1rnz/60/
The problem is that the delete button I want is not sticking within its slot (header).  I guess this is why using percentages is wrong in this case?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i think we use absolute on parent and then related to this we use relative to child of that parent..right? or i am wrong?

Comment: @Leothelion Exactly opposite.

Comment: @PraveenKumar but i am using position:absolute on parent and relative on child..and its working fine..is it wrong?

Comment: @Leothelion It should be parent relative and child absolute.

Comment: ohh thank you for useful info..ty so much

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have vertical height in percentage, you need to use the following code:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This way, you can control the `height` in percentages. This method is very much discouraged and will **not** work with frameworks like bootstrap. But you may give a try with adding a wrapper:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.first-top {
  height: 30%;
  background: #ccf;
}
.middle-top {
  height: 40%;
  background: #cfc;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-top">
  <!-- Give the list items here. -->
</div>
<div class="middle-top"></div>
<div class="first-top"></div>
```

Comment: as you are saying it wont work with bs and op asked question with bs then should you give answer like this? and to create a new one rather then checking the given code will help? sorry but just asking.

Comment: @Leothelion Agree with your logic. But I have given a non-bs version that works, and asked him to implement that. I really think OP is doing something totally unachievable.

Comment: as i have seen his code..he is using absolute but not relative..and structure is quite wrong too.hope op will edit and will explain more so we can help :)

Comment: @Leothelion I just commented to the OP that it's wrong and he needs to change. Gave instructions too. Check it out. :)